# How to use a JS array produced by PHP after a xmlhttprequest when user hits a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

My page can't access the produced JS array. When I view source, I can verify the data is there.

I use the following

User loads the page by selecting a option box
load.php:

```
<script>

var OptIndex= new array(); 

function Load()
{
   var str="";

   var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    document.getElementById("LoadDiv").innerHTML="Waiting..";
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("LoadDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
         }
      }


  xmlhttp.open("GET","adminload.php",true);
  xmlhttp.send();

}

</script>
```

adminload.php:

Then during the loading of adminload, I check to make sure a a php variable named "info" is set, if so I output to the OptIndex variable declared above like so

```
for($c=0;$c<$info->GetCount();$c++){
    //Get real index simply returns an index in an array, 
    //the values are right when outputted.
    echo "OptIndex.push(".$info->GetRealIndex($c).");";
}
```

Now back to Load.php:

After the data is loaded, I have the user press a button to run the following function

```
function GetInfo(index)
{
    var c=0;

    var str="";
    alert("I am working");//Fires off

    alert("Len: "+OptIndex.length);//Code dies here. If I change it to alert("Len: "+$(OptIndex).length); then len is 0. 
        for(c=0;c<OptIndex.length;c++)
        {

           var theitem="#Option_"+OptIndex[c]+"_"+index;//This is right
           str=str+"opt_"+OptIndex[c]+"="+$(theitem).val();
           if(c+1==OptIndex.length) break; 
          str= str+"&";

        }

}
```

Example data while GetInfo is running

```
OptIndex.push(3);OptIndex.push(4);OptIndex.push(5);OptIndex.push(6);OptIndex.push(7);OptIndex.push(8);OptIndex.push(9);OptIndex.push(10);OptIndex.push(11);OptIndex.push(12);OptIndex.push(13);OptIndex.push(14);OptIndex.push(15);OptIndex.push(16);OptIndex.push(17);OptIndex.push(18);OptIndex.push(19);OptIndex.push(21);OptIndex.push(22);OptIndex.push(23);OptIndex.push(24);OptIndex.push(25);OptIndex.push(26);OptIndex.push(27);OptIndex.push(28);OptIndex.push(29);
```

How do I get GetInfo to properly access the data in OptIndex?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Is the OptIndex before the getinfo right?

Comment: Yes, I declare OptIndex in load.php before getinfo is called. So OptIndex is declared on page load, and adminload tosses values onto the array

Comment: So OptIndex is ready. With firebug or similar have you tried debugging when inside getinfo? tried running OptIndex.length? results?

Comment: have you tried using `exec(xmlhttp.responseText)` in javascript? Your php code generates a bunch of javascript code but that javascript code never gets executed. Although i wouldnt recommend this way, a better alternative is echoing a json array instead.

Comment: Can you show a code example for the to json array? I can only think of encountering the same issue when trying that.